# nested for loop sum

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I wanted to get this sum of few specific column of each worksheet in that M2 cell of each worksheet.. but every time am getting 0 in that cell of each sheet.. other values are coming correctly.. its a very basic qs i know.. still cant find what going wrong in my code..

```
Sub Sort_database()
For i = 2 To 14
   Worksheets(i).Activate
    lastcol = 1
    While Cells(30, lastcol) <> ""
        lastcol = lastcol + 1
    Wend
    hfp = 0
    For counter = 4 To lastcol - 1
        pnt = 0
        For ihfp = 31 To 77
            pnt = pnt + Cells(ihfp, counter).Value
        Next ihfp
    Cells(78, counter).Value = pnt
    hfp = hfp + Cells(78, counter).Value
    Next counter
    Ranges("m2").Value = hfp
Next i
Sheet1.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `Ranges("m2").Value = hfp`? Do you mean `Range("M2").Value = hfp`? If you corrected this, it is working then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have some errors in your code, mainly `Ranges("m2").Value = hfp`  must be `Range("m2").Value = hfp`

see below for a working one

```
Sub Sort_database()
    Dim i As Long, lastCol As Long, counter As Double, ihfp As Long
    Dim hfp As Double, pnt As Double

    For i = 2 To 14
        Worksheets(i).Activate

        lastCol = 1
        While Cells(30, lastCol) <> ""
            lastCol = lastCol + 1
        Wend

        hfp = 0
        For counter = 4 To lastCol - 1
            pnt = 0
            For ihfp = 31 To 77
                pnt = pnt + Cells(ihfp, counter).Value
            Next ihfp
            .Cells(78, counter).Value = pnt
            hfp = hfp + Cells(78, counter).Value
        Next counter
        Range("m2").Value = hfp
    Next i
    Sheet1.Activate
End Sub
```

but `Activate`/`Select` `ActiveXX`/`Selection` is hardly a good coding practice and you'd better use fully qualified range references, possibly in conjunction with `With-End With` blocks, like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sort_database()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long, counter As Double

    For i = 2 To 14
        With Worksheets(i) '<--| reference i-th sheet
            lastCol = GetLastCol(.Cells(30, 4)) '<--| get currently reference worksheet last column rightwards of its cell "D30"
            For counter = 4 To lastCol
                .Cells(78, counter) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range(.Cells(31, counter), .Cells(77, counter))) '<--| use 'SUM()' built in Worksheet function
            Next counter
            .Range("M2").Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range(.Cells(78, 4), .Cells(78, lastCol))) '<-- '<--| use 'SUM()' built in Worksheet function and write its result in cell "M2" of currently referenced worksheet
        End With
    Next i
End Sub

Function GetLastCol(rng As Range) As Long
    GetLastCol = IIf(rng.End(xlToRight).Value = "", rng.Column, rng.End(xlToRight).Column)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanx a lot.. it did... and i understood ur code .. but apart from that `ranges('m2")` ... which i actually wrote incorrectly... what ware the wrong in my code logically.. ??  .. yes i use `activate` too much along with `select` ..

Comment: I found no "logical" errors in your code, meaning that it'd do what needed once amended of the syntax error.

Comment: ok i used ur code exactly.. but still all of my problem has not been solved... in some of my sheets am getting sum of only few columns and not all.. and as a result total is getting incorrect.. why is so..???

Comment: step through code to see what's happening: to do that just place cursor inside any executable statement and press F8 to make macro start. then keep pressing it to step to the next statement to be executed. At any time you can query any needed variable in Immediate Window (CTRL+G) (e.g.: type `?lastCol ` and press return to see current value of `lastCol` variable. and let me know

Comment: i had 16 sheets .. and checked everyone.. its taking `lastcol` variable correctly, all cells values correctly, and sum function within the loop `WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range(.Cells(31, counter), .Cells(77, counter)))` is giving correct result . but  `cells(78,counter)` is not showing the correct value... lot of gibberish.. some times 0 some time 50 .. some time the correct sum.. and that is reflecting on next sum..

Comment: sorry; there was a `.` missing before `Cells(78, counter) = ...`. Without that `.` `Cells()` would _ignore_ the preceding `With...` statement this referring to currently _active_ worksheet instead of currently looped one (i.e. `Worksheets(i)`). see edited code